# Persistent Threat and Rain of Steel

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers, opportunity-actions

Are you able to make opportunity attacks if you're dazed and have the feat Persistent Threat?

> **Persistent Threat** - While you are dazed, you can still flank enemies, and you can take an opportunity action if you haven't taken one since the start of your last turn.
>
> **Rain of Steel** - Any enemy that starts its turn adjacent to you takes 1[W] damage, as long as you are able to make opportunity attacks.

That said, Rain of Steel then works *while* you're dazed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rain of steel works, until you take an opportunity action.

> You can take opportunity actions if you haven't taken one since the start of your last turn.

This text permits you explicitly to take opportunity actions. Rain of Steel requires you to be able to take an opportunity attack which is a special kind of opportunity action.

Rain of Steel does not consume your opportunity action though so you are free to continue using it on each enemy until you've taken an opportunity attack of other opportunity action, at which time you would no longer meet the qualifications to use Rain.